# Why is the rgb CSS function not working in jQuery 1.7.1 anymore?

Tags: jquery, css

I have a function that animates a `div` and sets its background to white. Here is the code:

```
function(){
          $(this).animate(
                  {
                      left: '0',
                      backgroundColor: 'rgb(255,255,255)'
                  },
                  500,
                  'easeInSine'
          );//end animate
```

I updated jQuery from 1.6.3 to 1.7.1 and the background color does not change to white any more. Any ideas?

Post Update1 : complete code http://pastebin.com/JNWHuEQA

Post Update2 : site.css file http://pastebin.com/hJMQa77M

Post Update3 : I decided to remove completely the color plugin from the page, and to comment out the jquery.color.js line, since there is no reason to have it if it cannot cooperate with 1.7.1

Comment: `rgb(x,y,z)` should work fine. The problem must be elsewhere. Are you getting any JS errors?

Comment: Btw, you can't animate `backgroundColor` unless you're using jQuery UI or the backgroundColor animation plugin. That might be the problem.

Comment: I updated my original question with the complete web page code!

Comment: @Pekka : I used Chrome Javascript Console and I get this error :

Comment: Uncaught TypeError: Object function (a,b){return new e.fn.init(a, b, h)} has no method 'isNaN'

Comment: 1.6.3 on the other side gives a warning (but works):
28event.layerX and event.layerY are broken and deprecated in WebKit. They will be removed from the engine in the near future.

Comment: @skiabox: I smell a jQuery bug.

Comment: I've already made a post to the official jQuery forum but my post is waiting for 2 hours for moderation.

Comment: The color problem appears from 1.7.0 and beyond.

Comment: You're using the latest jquery.color.js from here? https://github.com/jquery/jquery-color

Comment: @dave-methvin I am looking at the source code of my file and the source code of the github url and it seems that the code is completely different!
Check the source of my file! (http://pastebin.com/9BbUpZjZ)

Comment: That version won't work with jQuery 1.7.x, it is using the undocumented jQuery.isNaN. Get a later version.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I don't know why it doesn't work, but you can simply use `#FFF`.

Comment: I replaced 'rgb(255,255,255)' with '#FFF' but the code still is not working with 1.7.1 (it works with both rgb and #FFF argument in 1.6.3)

Comment: From the documentation: “Animation Properties and Values
All animated properties should be animated to a single numeric value, except as noted below; most properties that are non-numeric cannot be animated using basic jQuery functionality (For example, width, height, or left can be animated but background-color cannot be, unless the jQuery.Color() plugin is used). Property values are treated as a number of pixels unless otherwise specified. The units em and % can be specified where applicable.”

Comment: I've added the complete html code along with the css file so that everyone can replicate the problem

Comment: The next time put it in a jsfiddle, it's easier. :)

Comment: I saw the above comment in their documentation and it says exactly that you must use the plugin.If you click in the example section, you can see clearly that they use the plugin (query.color.js) without any problem but for earlier versions of jQuery 1.6.x

Comment: Well, in my example the plugin works fine so something must be wrong in your whole code, I can't figure out what.

Comment: I believe that you should test it using a browser.That is the reason we write javascript.To be run at a client browser.Isn't it? :)

Comment: Have you seen my comments above about the chrome javascript console errors?

Comment: Err, using jsfiddle you still use your browser ;) that's just a tool to test it in a easier way, you can't execute javascript otherwise, haha. By the way, I'll have a look.